# how to implement collapsing image view like Google IO 2015 App using Design Library

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, googleio

How to implement collapsing toolbar layout design like Google IO 2015 using `Design Library`

**In Open Source Code of Google IO 2015, it is not implemented using Design Library (CoordinatorLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout etc)**

[image: Google IO 2015 Session Details Layout]

**Note** : In this the toolbar is at the bottom in upper section. I need the toolbar to be scrolling like this attached with the `textview` or any other `view` of upper section.

Comment: The source code of the app is available at https://github.com/google/iosched

Comment: @akash93 That i know. I already specified using Design Library and in open source it is not implemented using Design Library.

Comment: Have you tried moving the Toolbar out of the CollapsingToolbarLayout, but inside AppbarLayout?

Comment: @GPack, Yeah already tried that.

Comment: can you post your code about Toolbar out of the CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally i was able to implement it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vipul.myapplication.ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:title=" "
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />-->

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/large_text" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Im having some issues with fitsSystemWindows, my toolbar is behind the status bar, adding  android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on the coordinator layout and in the appbarlayout its working like a charm, thnks

Answer (score -2):

The code below will do what you want to do:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/header"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

// The rest of the content goes here...

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Go [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.za/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for more information on the material design library

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering and this code will not work.