# How to make this profile picture moving with Collapsing Toolbar Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to make a layout like this. But I did not know how to make profile picture moving with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I need help.

[image: See The Picture here]

Like the above picture

Comment: its a collapsible view.

Comment: Provide some code whatever you tried

Comment: see this to get idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386712/how-to-implement-collapsing-image-view-like-google-io-2015-app-using-design-libr and http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: I am only facing issues with the profile picture.

Comment: @MujahidRasool try this http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: see https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar

Comment: @MujahidRasool have a look here: https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample . Task is not easy, but not impossible either ... good luck! :)

Comment: @MujahidRasool Check my answer. Is that what you want? or you are trying to make a layout exactly like this? The rest(A `view`-`Button` and etc) won't be a problem but, let me know if you're trying to do so.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I want to make layout like this

Comment: @MujahidRasool Updated the answer. please take a look. It's possible by adding a view and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated (*just like the layout you want*)** : It is possible by adding a `CircleImageView` inside `CoordinatorLayout` so i won't be hidden after scrolling with anchoring to `AppbarLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:title="My Toolbar" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <!--Maybe a button or etc...-->


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="My TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteColor" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your large text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img_profile"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample app you can possibly share?

Comment: Hey can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72693058/11560810)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code tested

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_height"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            >


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_small"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/tequila_name"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_xlarge"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_xxsmall"
                    android:text="@string/tequila_tagline"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/spacing_xsmall"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/lorem"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_medium"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.collapsing"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:title=""
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/tequila_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_large"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:src="@drawable/ninja"
    app:border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:border_width="@dimen/border_width"
    app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
    app:finalXPosition="@dimen/spacing_small"
    app:finalYPosition="@dimen/spacing_small"
    app:finalToolbarHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can try the below code, basically, instead of handling complex calculations for achieving that behavior using the collapsable toolbar, I used Motionlayout to achieve this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_default" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_user_thumb"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_background"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/RoundedShape" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_back"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_back" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        layout="@layout/content_scroll"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_user_thumb" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

**content_scroll.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="@string/large_text" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**activity_main_scene.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet />
        <OnSwipe
            motion:dragDirection="dragUp"
            motion:touchAnchorId="@+id/layout" />
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/iv_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/iv_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Here i also attached the GitHub of the repo: https://github.com/asadmukhtar28/ToolBar-UX.

Comment: Hey @AsadMukhtar can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72693058/11560810)